# A shortcut to connect with Microsoft Remote Desktop without password on Mac

Tags: windows, macos, remote-desktop, passwords

On a local area network I want to connect to a Windows PC from a Mac using Microsoft Remote Desktop and stored credentials using a double-click on an icon without other steps.

What I managed to do:

1. Create an entry in Microsoft Remote Desktop application define username and password, double-click on it and connect without being asked for the password (in short: run Remote Desktop app, and double-click on the connection)
2. Export the entry to an `.rdp` file in filesystem, double-click on it and then I am greeted with a `Invalid login credentials. Please re-enter` message`, I can provide a password and log on (in short: double-click and enter the password)

What I want to do is to have my login credentials stored somehow with the `.rdp` file (if necessary, I accept the security risk of adding the password in clear text). Adding a string value `password` did not work.

Is there any way to achieve this?

<sup>I use Microsoft Remote Desktop 8.0.22 on El Capitan and connect to Windows 7, but other versions behaved in exactly the same way.</sup>

Comment: I got this working a while back and it was not simple, something to do with certificates being passed between machines that allows domain / machine level fiddling on the host side to reduce the default cryptography level? Will research more later...

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to achieve this today (in a similar way to what the Windows client does where the password is saved).

For feature requests and ideas, I suggest going to [this site](http://aka.ms/uservoice-rdmac). In particular, [this idea](https://remotedesktop.uservoice.com/forums/287834-remote-desktop-for-mac/suggestions/8130597-allow-exported-config-files-to-use-password-saved) looks similar to yours.